# Lottory probability

Tags: probability

A Lotto consists of choosing 6 different numbers out of 1 to 49. What is the probability that the same sequence of six numbers does not appear twice in 3016 drawings.

Assumption is the order of the numbers does not matter for winning. Also I assumed that the 3016 drawing do not matter this could be error on my part.

So the chances of any particular sequence of numbers being drawn is
$$ \frac{1}{\binom {49}6}  $$

My reasoning from that point is that the sequence has the same probability, $ \frac{1}{\binom {49}6} $, of being picked again, so the probability of getting the same sequence of six numbers twice is

$$ \frac{1}{\binom {49}6^2} $$

and from that the probability that the same sequence of six does not appear is $$ 1 - \frac{1}{\binom {49}6^2} $$

I am looking to see if my reasoning is correct any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Your mistake is in saying "the probability of getting the same sequence of six numbers twice is $\frac{1}{{{49}\choose{6}}^2}$".  That's the probability of getting a *specific* six numbers twice, not the probability of getting any six numbers twice.

Comment: Assuming that Gregory Grant has interpreted the question correctly, deriving an exact answer is probably computationally a pain in the neck.  (Sorry to get all technical.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account that no one drawing can be the same as any of the previous draws and that there are 3016 draws. For two draws the probability is merely based on the probability that the second doesn't match the first. So even if only two draws are made you'd get $\frac{\binom{49}{6} -1}{\binom{49}{6}}$ or $1-\frac{1}{\binom{49}{6}}$.

Use the idea that for the first draw it doesn't matter which is drawn, after this there is only one combination that is not permitted, so for the second you get a probability of $\frac{\binom{49}{6} -1}{\binom{49}{6}}$, then for the next you cannot draw one of the previous two, and repeat this logic. You could then write the probability as the product $\Pi_{n=1}^{3015} \frac{\binom{49}{6} -n}{\binom{49}{6}}$.